# "HashMap is Full" при использовании TryAdd в Unity Job System

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я ещё не особо разбираюсь в Job System, но после того как я наконец-то смог использовать HashMap внутри самого job я столкнулся с ошибкой
`InvalidOperationException: HashMap is full`
[image: InvalidOperationException: HashMap is full]

На Unity форумах я не нашёл ничего что могло бы мне помочь.
Ошибка вызывается в этой строке:
`writePipeByPosition.TryAdd(position, tempPipe);`
Эта строка мне нужна для того что бы перезаписывать/изменять данные "трубы" (pipe). Я не знаю насколько точно я дал понять мою проблему, но заранее спасибо, всё что нужно уточняйте.

Вот так выглядит сам IJobParallelFor (убрал всё лишнее):

```
private struct MovingJob : IJobParallelFor {
    [ReadOnly] public NativeArray<Resource> resourcesArray;
    public NativeArray<Matrix4x4> matricesArray;
    public NativeHashMap<Vector3Int, Pipe>.ReadOnly readPipeByPosition;
    public NativeParallelHashMap<Vector3Int, Pipe>.ParallelWriter writePipeByPosition;

    public void Execute(int index) {
        Matrix4x4 matrix = matricesArray[index];
        Vector3Int position = Vector3Int.FloorToInt(new(matrix.m03, matrix.m13, matrix.m23));
        if (readPipeByPosition.TryGetValue(position, out Pipe tempPipe)) {
            writePipeByPosition.TryAdd(position, tempPipe);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот как выглядит вызов данной структуры (также убрал всё лишнее):

```
private void Update() {
    if (resourceList.Count > 0) {
        int count = resourceList.Count;
        NativeArray<Matrix4x4> matricesArray = new(matricesList.ToArray(), Allocator.TempJob);
        NativeHashMap<Vector3Int, Pipe> nativeReadHashMap = new(pipeManager.pipeComponentByPosition.Count, Allocator.TempJob);
        NativeParallelHashMap<Vector3Int, Pipe> nativeWriteHashMap = new(pipeManager.pipeComponentByPosition.Count, Allocator.TempJob);
        foreach (var kvp in pipeManager.pipeComponentByPosition) {
            nativeReadHashMap.TryAdd(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
        var movingJob = new MovingJob {
            matricesArray = matricesArray,
            readPipeByPosition = nativeReadHashMap.AsReadOnly(),
            writePipeByPosition = nativeWriteHashMap.AsParallelWriter()
        };
        JobHandle movingJobHandle = movingJob.Schedule(count, 32);
        movingJobHandle.Complete();
        matricesArray.Dispose();
        nativeReadHashMap.Dispose();
        nativeWriteHashMap.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: HashMap is full = HashMap полон. Похоже, что того размера, который ты передаешь при создании хэшмапы недостаточно. Вообще непонятно зачем здесь эта джоба, потому что на ее запуск и заполнение `nativeReadHashMap` времени уйдет больше, чем на выполнение самой джобы. Ну и работать в билде, если использовать burst, оно скорее всего не будет, т.к. он не воспринимает дефолтную юнитевскую математику, но воспринимает `Unity.Mathematics` (ту, что с float3, а не Vector3)

Comment: @KOTlK Эта джоба подальше будет расширяться и я надеюсь что потом она будет более производительной в перспективе чем если я буду писать код напрямую. Проблем с Vector3 не заметил код работает как надо. Проблема в том что допустим я поставлю размер хэшмапы в единицу (потому что есть только 1 труба на карте), есть шанс что пока оно будет идти по списку ```resourceList```, на какой-то из итераций может вылететь эта ошибка с заполнением хэшмапы (например размер списка 100, при первой попытке ошибка была на 67 элементе, на второй на 98)